# Android AlarmManager.setRepeating()

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager, broadcast

Will this code work?

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmType, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 15000, 15000, pendingIntent);
```

I need execute the same task every 15 minutes after installing the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:

No, try

```
long interval = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 minutes
alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmType, SystemClock.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pendingIntent);
```

It will be activated first time after 15 minutes from launch and will be activated every 15 minutes from that.

**Long answer**:

Well, I strongly refer you to the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference).
If you look at AlarmManamger.setRepeating() [method signature](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), you will see that it accepts both start time and interval duration in milliseconds. More over, it require Unix Time as start time. Although `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` provides time in milliseconds, it doesn't give you Unix Time. What it returns it time elapsed from boot. `SystemClock.currentTimeMillins()` is what you need in this scenario.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can't do it.

My code is

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can't do it.

My code is : [`code`]

Comment: class PrincipalWidget : AppWidgetProvider
    {        
        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            context.StartService(new Intent(context, typeof(UpdateService)));
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService (Context.AlarmService);      
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,  typeof(UpdateService));
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);  long interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;
 am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc, 5000 , interval, pi); }

Comment: What exactly is your problem with code? Can you please update your answer providing all related code (including code in comments).

Comment: inteval = 1*60*1000;

[am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc, 5000 , interval, pi); ]

no se repite acada 1 minuto

le puse 1 munuto para probar. e interpreto que se inicia a los 5 segundo

Comment: interval = 1 * 60 * 1000; [ `am.SetRepeating ( AlarmType.Rtc , 5000 , intervalo, pi) ;` ] Is not repeated every one minute. i put one minute to try. and I interpret that starts at the 5 seconds

Comment: replace `5000` with `SystemClock.currentTimeMillis()`: `am.SetRepeating ( AlarmType.Rtc , 5000 , intervalo, pi);`